# Extract inner list content and write to csv with writerow loop

Tags: python

How do I write only content of the inner loop in rows to csv file?

```
lst=[['apple'], ['banana'], ['cantaloupe'], ['durian']]
f = writer(open("abcd.file", 'w', newline = ''), delimiter=",")
for row in lst:
   f.writerow(["xoxo", row, '', '', '', ''])
```

**got:**

```
xoxo,['apple'],,,,
xoxo,['banana'],,,,
xoxo,['cantaloupe'],,,,
xoxo,['durian'],,,,
```

**want in abcd.file:**

```
xoxo,apple,,,,
xoxo,banana,,,,
xoxo,cantaloupe,,,,
xoxo,durian,,,,
```

Comment: `f.writerow(["xoxo", row[0], '', '', '', ''])` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `lst` is a list inside a list, so in order to print the item inside you need to use `[0]`

try this:

```
lst=[['apple'], ['banana'], ['cantaloupe'], ['durian']]
f = writer(open("abcd.file", 'w', newline = ''), delimiter=",")
for row in lst:
   f.writerow(["xoxo", row[0], '', '', '', ''])
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `lst` list is always with the same structure, you can just use :

```py
for row in lst:
   f.writerow(["xoxo", row[0], '', '', '', ''])
```